# How to plot a set of unit vectors whose angles are chosen from a normal distribution using pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to represent `N` unit vectors whose angles are chosen from a normal distribution say (`mean=90, sd=10`) like in the picture below.

I would like to know how I could draw the same using `pgfplots`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={gauss(\x)=exp(-pow(\x/10,2));},>=stealth]
 \begin{axis}[hide axis,xmin=-1,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{0}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (90:1);
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,10}{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{\myangle+1/(gauss(\myangle))}
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[->] (0,0) -- (90+\myangle:1);
   \noexpand\draw[->] (0,0) -- (90-\myangle:1);}
   \temp 
  }
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a polar axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={gauss(\x)=exp(-pow(\x/10,2));},>=stealth]
 \begin{polaraxis}[ymax=1,xmin=0,xmax=180,ytick=\empty]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{0}
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (90,1);
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,10}{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{\myangle+1/(gauss(\myangle))}
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[->] (0,0) -- (90+\myangle,1);
   \noexpand\draw[->] (0,0) -- (90-\myangle,1);}
   \temp 
  }
 \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This serves the purpose. Thank you. I would like to know if there is a way to label it so that the angles can be read off the plot? Or include a reference line to indicate, say, 0 degree and 180 degree?

Comment: @user206089 Of course. Use a polar axis. I added an example.

Comment: Can I also know how to have ticks associated with angles and not lines (gray coloured) in the above plot?. I am just being a little picky. This helps me. Thank you.

Comment: @user206089 To remove the gray lines, add `grid=none` to the option of the `axis`, i.e. `\begin{polaraxis}[ymax=1,xmin=0,xmax=180,ytick=\empty,grid=none]`.

Comment: And, how can I change the number of vectors in the plot to say, 100? and also have a very thin, gray semicircle instead of the black one right now? Sorry for the number of questions.

Comment: @user206089 `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,50}{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{\myangle+1/(5.3*gauss(\myangle))}
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[->] (0,0) -- (90+\myangle,1);
   \noexpand\draw[->] (0,0) -- (90-\myangle,1);}
   \temp 
  }` .